# How can I get Google Adsense to access pages in a login area when login is with JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, authentication, adsense

I have a site that I want to include Google Adsense ads on, where the ads only appear inside an area that is accessed when a user logs in.

In the Google Adsense interface, one can go to `Account Settings -> Access and authorization -> Crawler access` and set up a login account for the Google web crawler to see the login area.

However, the three types of login available are `POST`, `GET` and `htaccess`. I have tried all three and none work.

In my case, the user logs in by going to a page called login.html, where they enter their login information, and press a button that is driven by Javascript. It sends JSON data to the server, and if the user is okay, then they are redirected to a different page.

I can't see if there's a way to configure Adsense to deal with this. When I test the login access, it shows my the login screen only, which seems to indicate it stops there and does not actually access the restricted pages.

Is there something I can do to make sure that Google Adsense can login while preserving my login method?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you make a request similar to the **ajax** request your normally do.

`Restricted Directory or URL`: www.example.com/members/

`Login URL`: www.example.com/login.ajax.php

`Login method`: POST or GET depending on whether the parameters of your ajax request are send as POST data or GET data.

`Parameters`: Add all the parameters which you send along with ajax request normally. So this will likely be a `usr` and `pwd` parameter. And if you are sending a single parameters with both the usr and pwd then that's also fine, as you can simply make a parameter like `data` (depending on what you call it in your code) with `{usr:"adsense_username",pwd:"password"}` as a literal string for example.

If you have trouble figuring it out please copy the code which does the ajax request.

Answer (score -1):

Well I guess that you are loggin in the same domain while adsense is doing Json from a different domain. I advice you JsonP. It will work cross domain

Comment: Adsense is doing a non-javascript request in the first place (the crawler) using the cookies to 'authenticate' for all the requests in the restricted directory or URL.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you could give a link in get (jsonp) to allow to go throu so instead of a javascript request I thought it could follow a link that would generate a session (cookies?). But if it isn't the case sorry for bothering